# How to push an object to array in data properties in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to push object into array inside data properties in my nuxt project. but i am getting error like

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

here is my js part

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        gallery: [{
          id: null,
          imgurl: null
        }]
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async uploadGallery() {
      var myimg = "imageurl getting after upload";
      var imgData = {};
      imgData['imgurl'] = myimg;
      imgData['id'] = "someid";
      this.form.gallery.push(imgData);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This means that `this.form.gallery` is `undefined` at some point. You probably have some async issues somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Also, feel free to write it like this `imgData.imgurl`, simpler.

Comment: when are you calling this method ?

Comment: pardon me ! it was all typo issue on my backend side, in asyncdata i replace local form data from using returned value from api. in backend i mistyped gallery as galley, thats why i was facing such issue.

Comment: 'this' content is available at the "fetch" hook. You are probably calling the method in created hook. More information about nuxt life cycle: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1):

l tried your code like above. When l clicked the button, it was working. Probably you couldn't reach form.gallery becuse triggered uploadGallery is in wrong life cycle hooks.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{form.gallery}}
     <button @click="uploadGallery">click</button>
  </div> 
</template>
```